# Spring Security OAuth 1.0a: providing already existing tokens

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth

I'd like to secure a simple rest web service developed using Jersey using Spring OAuth v1.0a, and I have a questions about it. First, a brief doubt: I've found some examples involving Spring-MVC, is it mandatory to include it? As I'm trying to make my application as light as possibile, it would be nice if I could leave Spring-MVC out.

Apart from that, my biggest issue is about token handling, and particularly about dealing with the steps that lead a user to access an OAuth protected area. From what I got to understand, trying to access a protected area automatically triggers the token generation process, starting from the creation of the unauthorized request token. Unfortunately, this workflow doesn't fit my needs as the scenario I have to deal with involves a user which is already in possess of an authorized access token, and only needs to provide it in order to be granted access to a protected resource. Would it be possibile to override the token generation mechanism with a token retrieval (from a POST/GET for instance) and verification process?
Thank you very much for your effort.

EDIT: (trying to explain things more clearly)

Assume this is the part in my XML where I describe my resource:

```
<oauth:resource id="OAuthExperimentsRestrictedArea"
                    key="thisIsExactlyTheConsumerKey"
                    secret="...andThisIsExactlyTheSecret"
                    request-token-url="http://localhost:8080/OauthExperiments/oauth/request_token"
                    user-authorization-url="http://localhost:8080/OauthExperiments/oauth/confirm_access"
                    access-token-url="http://localhost:8080/OauthExperiments/oauth/access_token" />
```

What I can't really get to understand is how or where should I pass an already valid access token in case I had it. By trying to directly access the resource via a simple direct link not providing any token, my application would begin the token creation process redirecting me first to request-token-url, next to user-authorization-url and finally to access-token-url. What I need to achieve is the possibility to skip this when I already have a valid token, but what I'm missing is how to do that, where to pass the token (is there a default bean for that? should I pass it as a parameter with a particular name?).
My goal is to have the possibility to delegate even external services for token verification, so what I'm ultimately trying to find is some kind of hook for such procedure. I hope I've explained the whole scenario clearly enough.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm even more sure I don't understand the question now, but at least I'm confused in a different way. An `<oauth:resource/>` is a consumer feature (and up to now I had assumed you were protecting a resource server side, i.e. as a service provider). So is the question, how to use Spring OAuth to consume a remote service protected by OAuth 1.0 if you already have an access token? What is the localhost:8080 server in your configuration? Don't you need that to get the access token? Where is your token provider exactly?

Comment: Ok, it is perhaps clear now that I may be making a bit of confusion here, and hence I could use some clarifications: isn't that code what I should put in my client app? Yes, I'm protecting a server side resource (a service) and I'm accessing this service from a web application, which we can assume is not necessarily hosted on the same server. Let's dismiss for a second the token generation process, say we just have it. Yes, I'd say the question would exactly be how to use Spring OAuth to consume a remote service protected by OAuth 1.0a if you already have an access token.

Answer (score 1):

That's 2 questions?

- Spring MVC is not needed for securing a resource (it's all Spring Security via Servlet Filters).
- The second question is about what to do if you have a valid access token and as a consumer you want to send valid requests and access protected resources. A new token would not need to be generated if the request is already authorized.

The answer to the second question is that you need to populate the `OAuthSecurityContext` (via a thread local managed by `OAuthSecurityContextHolder`). Obviously you need to be careful to clear it when you are finished. Normally this context is populated by a filter (`OAuthConsumerContextFilter`)  so you can see how that manages the context and copy it. I can't say I like this model much, but that's the way it was implemented (the OAuth2 implementation changed quite a while ago, before 1.0).

Comment: I think you answered his 2nd part but for clarity.  It is the routing that determine whether the resource is protected by the security filter and that the routing has to be implemented so that the token generation occurs outside of the Security filters path.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'm trying to make it clearer as perhaps it's not. Fact is that I actually don't know how to skip the whole token generation part. Where and how should I be passing the token? As a URL paramter? To the resource directly? I'm editing my question and try to improve it if possibile.

Comment: And by the way indeed no, I wouldn't need new tokens at all, in fact new token generation is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: Setting the OAuthSecurityContextHolder with the OAuthSecurityContext populated with the access token worked for my use case (did it in a Spring Integration Service Activator); however, it would be nice if the access token and token secret could be added directly to the oauth:resource element, as OP hinted at.